IntelliJ Scala warning with parameterized type in compiled JAR
I have Scala code with parameterized types like this:
val foo: SomeParameterizedType[_ <: Product with Serializable] =
  new SomeParameterizedType[Foo](arguments)

val bar: SomeParameterizedType[_ <: Product with Serializable] =
  new SomeParameterizedType[Bar](arguments)

where SomeParameterizedType is class with a type parameter and Foo and Bar are both case classes.
Foo comes from a compiled JAR file (via standard Maven dependency), and Bar is part of the same IntelliJ project.
What I'm noticing is, IntelliJ will flag foo but not bar with a type mismatch warning ("type Foo does not conform to the upper bound Product with Serializable...")
Rebuilding the project works, and clean build from Maven works.  The only issue is the IDE warning.
Any idea how to fix this -- something in IntelliJ config I'm missing?

When you say "Foo is in a compiled JAR file", do you mean that it's retrieved from a standard Maven dependency? Or something else?

@GaëlJ yes, Maven dependency.  Edited question for clarity.

If you're on the latest IntelliJ and Scala plugin versions, could be worth opening an issue to Jetbrains. I never faced this.
